# How to use BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION?

Tags: c++, exception, boost

How do I use the `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` macro? What goes in as parameters? I have no clue and I cannot seem to find any readable examples.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just pass an exception object to it:

```
BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(std::range_error("Index out of range"));
```

It will wrap the exception to make it derive from class `boost::exception` (if it's not already a child of it), and add info like source file and line.

The [Boost.Exception FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/exception/doc/frequently_asked_questions.html) has good insights on advantages and use examples.

Comment: Sorry, missed a semicolon